# Base64 Exception in Java

Tags: java, soap, pdf-generation

I am getting Bad Base64 input character at 0: 37(decimal) exception while performing the following operation in java.

```
static void byteArrayToFile(byte[] bArray) {  
        try {  
            // Create file  
            String pathName = AppConfig.getInstance().getConfigValue("webapp.root") + File.separator + "temp"+File.separator+"heasas.pdf";
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(pathName);  
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);  
            for (Byte b: bArray) {  
                out.write(b);  
            }  
            out.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
        }
```

Hi all, On recieving Soap message from 3rd party,i wrote fallowing snippet of code to get 
content of attachment :
Object content = attachment1.getContent();
writePdf(content);

```
private void writePdf(Object content) throws IOException, PrintException, DocumentException {
        String str = content.toString();
        byte[] b = Base64.decode(str);
        byteArrayToFile(b);

}
```

Here is my logic to convert byte array to pdf:

```
static void byteArrayToFile(byte[] bArray) {  
    try {  
        // Create file  
        String pathName = AppConfig.getInstance().getConfigValue("webapp.root") + File.separator + "temp"+File.separator+"heasas.pdf";
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(pathName);  
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);  
        for (Byte b: bArray) {  
            out.write(b);  
        }  
        out.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
    }  
}
```

can anybody suggest me the solution now please......

Comment: Can you paste the exact exception stacktrace. `e.printStacktrace()` should do the trick in your `catch` block.

Comment: Which line specifically is causing the error? I'm suspecting it's the `out.write(b);`, which means the problem is in `for (Byte b: bArray)`, which is writing what you received as `byte[] bArray` to the function. So you need to look at what's being passed in to `bArray` in the function call. There's no way we can see that value, because you didn't provide it. You should learn to use the debugger (or at least the stack trace) to track errors like this down.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FileWriter javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> FileWriter is meant for writing streams of characters. For writing streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileOutputStream.